# How to change fontsize of individual legend entries in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

What I'm trying to do is control the fontsize of individual entries in a legend in pyplot. That is, I want the first entry to be one size, and the second entry to be another. This was my attempt at a solution, which does not work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1,5,0.5)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,x,label='Curve 1')
plt.plot(x,2*x,label='Curve 2')
leg = plt.legend(loc = 0, fontsize = 'small')
leg.get_texts()[0].set_fontsize('medium')
plt.show()
```

My expectation is that the default size for all legend entries would 'small'. I then get a list of the Text objects, and change the fontsize for only a single Text object to medium. However, for some reason this changes all Text object fontsizes to medium, rather than just the single one I actually changed. I find this odd since I can individually set other properties such as text color in this manner.

Ultimately, I just need some way to change an individual entry's fontsize for a legend.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that the font of each legend entry is managed by an instance of `matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties`. The thing is: each entry doesn't have its own `FontProperties`... they all share the same one. This is verified by writing:

```
>>> t1, t2 = leg.get_texts()
>>> t1.get_fontproperties() is t2.get_fontproperties()
True
```

So if you change the size of the first entry, the size of the second entry is automatically changed along with it.

The "hack" to get around this is to simply create a distinct instance of `FontProperties` for each legend entry:

```
x = np.arange(1,5,0.5)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,x,label='Curve 1')
plt.plot(x,2*x,label='Curve 2')
leg = plt.legend(loc = 0, fontsize = 'small')

t1, t2 = leg.get_texts()
# here we create the distinct instance
t1._fontproperties = t2._fontproperties.copy()
t1.set_size('medium')

plt.show()
```

And now the sizing is correct:

[image]

Comment: Not sure of when it was added, but this also works for me (matplotlib 1.5.3): `t1.set_fontproperties(t1.get_fontproperties())`. This has the advantage of not relying on protected Text attributes (i.e. `_fontproperties`). Note that even if you assign the FontProperties to the same object you took them from (`t1` in this case), it still makes a copy internally. See also [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3356/)

Answer (score 1):

A much easier method is possible, if you activate LaTeX for the text rendering in your plots. You achieve that effortless, with an extra command line after your 'imports':

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Now you can change the size of any particular string by specifying with an `r` at the beginning of the string that is to be processed with LaTeX, and add your desired [size command for LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Built-in_sizes) inside (`\small, \Large, \Huge,` etc.).
For example:

```
r'\Large Curve 1'
```

Look at your adapted code. It took only minor changes!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('text', usetex=True) #Added LaTeX processing

x = np.arange(1,5,0.5)
plt.figure(1)
#Added LaTeX size commands on the formatted String
plt.plot(x,x,label=r'\Large Curve 1')
plt.plot(x,2*x,label=r'\Huge Curve 2')
plt.legend(loc = 0, fontsize = 'small')
#leg.get_texts()[0].set_fontsize('medium')
plt.show()
```

So you get this:

[image]